# Take after with

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I say "I took after my father his eyes" ?

Or the only accessible option is " I take after my father. I have green pupils" ???

May I say " ii take after my father with his green eyes?"?

Comment: Your pupils aren't green.  Your *iris* might be green. The pupil is the black hole in the middle of the eye. The iris is the coloured ring that might be blue, green or brown

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot say, "I took after my father his eyes." This is not grammatically correct.

You can say, " I take after my father. I have green eyes." Please note, the pupil is the black, circular opening in the centre of the eye.  The iris is the coloured ring that surrounds the pupil. When people talk about eye colour, they are almost always talking about the colour of the iris.

It is quite common in English to use the verb 'got' to describe inherited traits. For example:

> I get my green eyes from my father, but my blonde hair from my mother.

It is also quite common the phrase 'I have my' to describe inherited traits. For example:

> I have my father's green eyes, but my mother's blonde hair.

It is also quite acceptable to say, "I take after my father with his green eyes".